# Multiple languages, emojis and input sources in virtual Accessibility Keyboard in MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, accessibility

In MacOS's on-screen virtual keyboard for accessibility, I'd love to learn about the readiness of multi-language support. More specifically:

1. Languages other than English - is there some easy or built-in way to address the need for multi-lingual users? I can think about various possible solutions (and I'd love to both hear about other solutions and if mine are feasible/available), whether by

   - showing a "language switcher" button (to function the same as the regular globe key/button in physical keyboards of Mac/Apple)
   - automatic switching to the currently chosen language of the global input-source in the system (eg by using the language button/icon in the menu bar, and it's selection menu)
   - to show multiple virtual keyboards simultaneously (whether with separate windows, or showing 2 language panels in the same window).
2. Emojis -

   - Is it possible to show Emojis in the on-screen keyboard? I'd love to know if macOS supports some standard/builtin keyboard keys-layout for emojis (eg similar to the emoji keyboard in iPhone/iOS)
   - Also, is it possible to show some popular emojis, right within the main keyboard (just like showing numbers, alongside letters), instead of changing the input-source or keyboard layout to "Emojis" specifically?

If nothing of the above is available, then - is the only way is to create custom panels by myself, or to use the dedicated Emoji/character-map popup tool (which is not part of the Accessibility Keyboard and works independently)?

Answer (score 0):

The accessibility keyboard/keyboard viewer should always mirror your current language input source.  It will also mirror any custom input source you create, for example with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/), which could include emojis or other symbols.

I don’t think multiple keyboards are possible, but [customization](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/panel-editor-switch-control-accessibility-mh43606/13.0/mac/13.0) may offer some options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of what you ask, though not necessarily exactly in the way you wanted. I've tried to squeeze as much of this as I can into one big picture, because there are a lot of questions wrapped in one here…

Language Switcher - can be added to the menu bar; Keyboard > Input Sources > 'Show Input menu in menu bar'
Auto-switching - just below 'show input menu'
Multiple virtual keyboads - not possible, the virtual keyboard will switch language as you do.

Emojis - not from the virtual keyboard, but from the 'Emojis & Symbols' panel. Click the little [image] symbol, top right of the panel to change from 'consumer' to 'pro' view.
It will stack your most commonly-used ones at the top of the 'consumer' view.

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
[image]